# open file and load text using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm writing code and found a problem in taking data from file using php. So the goal is to take information from txt file and create div blocs. SO here I have on problem and one question, I hope that you can help me with that.

So here is a problem - I open a file and start reading but some how it is continue reading file even if it is empty. It is can not stop.

here is a code -

```
<?php
    $flis = fopen ("users/".$IDN."/list.txt",'r');
    $f= 1;
    while (!feof($flis))
        {
            $CID = fgets ($flis, 99);
            echo $f;
            $f++;
        }
        fclose($flis);
?>
```

So I planing have a file with a lot of strings but it can not stop reading even an empty file, Please help me to find a mistake.
Also in  while I planing to create a new block div . so here is a new question- how is better to create a div block? I use printf like that -

```
 printf ("
<div id=\"message_contact\">
            <a>
                <div id=\"conto\">  
                </div>          
            </a>
        </div>
    ");
```

But the problem is that the block will be a complex and plus it suppose to be a php function inside the block to put the information inside from database to that block. So can u recommend other methods to realize it?

Comment: Show us example contents of `list.txt`.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use the include statement?

Comment: include for html blocks? -ok but im not sure.

Comment: list.txt - empty, any empty txt file. but the problem not in the file, empty or just a one word don't suppose influent, because I just need to read it.

Comment: Thank you. Requesting permission to launch myself into orbit now.

Comment: Houston, Houston... Permission in launch approved. Launch in 10, 9, 8 ...

Comment: problem solved thanks everyone. It is also will be cool to understand why my variant didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [foreach](https://php.net/manual/pl/control-structures.foreach.php), Luke! And also [`file_get_contents`](https://php.net/manual/pl/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`explode`](https://php.net/explode).

```
<?php
$path = 'users/' . $IDN . '/list.txt';
$contents = file_get_contents($path);
$lines = explode("\n", $contents);
?>

<div id="message_contact">

<?php
    foreach ($lines as $line)
    {
?>
    <a>
        <!-- DIV inside A? Okay! -->
        <div id="conto">
            <?php echo trim($line); ?>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php
    }
?>

</div>
```

Note how I called `trim()` inside `<div>`. Poof, PHP inside HTML!

Comment: thanks for your help Vader, the code is work. It is also will be cool to understand why my variant didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Edit, line by line

```
<?php
    $flis = "users/".$IDN."/list.txt";
    $fc = file_get_contents($fils);
    $fca = explode("\n", $fc);
    foreach ($fca as $line) {
      echo $line;
      // OR
      include('template.php');
    }
?>
```

template.php:

```
<div id="message_contact">
    <a>
        <div id="conto">
            <?php echo $line; ?>
        </div>          
    </a>
</div>
```

How's that?

Comment: not the php read every line in txt file and  create the div block. So if it is 10 lines then it is suppose to create a 10 blocks. So my bigest problem is why it can not finish read the file, it is go to infinity even if it is empty. And another question is how is better to include the div block in this process... the your code is two different things, read my post above and see the code that I have... Thanks